# proof that the absolute condition number of the heaviside function is infinite?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-calculus

The Heaviside Step Function is given by:

$$
\begin{align*}
H(x) = \Theta = \left\{\begin{array}{c}
    0,if \quad x<0 \\
    1, if \quad x \geq 0
\end{array}\right.
\end{align*}
$$

I should now proof that the absolute condition number is $\infty$. I know there is this equation:

$‖f (\tilde{x}) − f (x)‖ ≤ k_{abs} ‖\tilde{x} − x‖ + σ(‖\tilde{x} − x‖)$

and I normally know how to calculate the absolute condition number but since this function is not continuously differentiable I have no clue how to start with this task. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How about a reference that explains $\sigma$?  Or should that be $o$ ?

Answer (score 0):

If both $x$ and $\tilde x$ are $\ge 0$, you have that $f(x)=f(\tilde x)=1$ and so,

$$
|f(x)-f(\tilde x)| = 0 \leq k|x-\tilde x| 
$$

holds for any $k$. The same happens in $x,\tilde x <0$.The actual restrictions on $k$ appear when $x$ and $\tilde x$ have different signs. In that case, the inequality
$$
|f(x)-f(\tilde x)| = 1 \leq k |x-\tilde x|
$$

can only hold for all such $x, \tilde x$ if $k = \infty$. For instance,

$$
|f(-1/n) - f(1/n)| = 1 \leq \frac{2k}{n}
$$

implies that we should have $k\ge \frac n2$ for all $n$.

Comment: How are you dealing with $\sigma$ (whatever that might be)?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC The $\sigma$ is probably just the "little o". I am dealing with it in the sense that the zero function is $o(|x-\tilde x|)$.